# Adding an additional motor to a load

Tags: induction-motor, power-factor-correction, reactive-power, synchronous-motor

You have a 500kVA load with a power factor of 0.6 lag. You add an additional synchronous motor with an input of 80kW and max power factor of 0.8 leading.
Determine the reactive power and the overall power factor.

Can anyone help me with this question? I don't even know where to start. I don't think my teacher even knows how to do it.

Thanks.

---

Is this correct?

***Existing installation***

$$P=S\cdot pf = 500\cdot 0.6 = 300\text{ kW}$$

$$Q=\sqrt{500^2-300^2} = 400\text{ KVAR}$$

$$S=500\text{ kVA}$$

***New synchronous motor***

$$P=80\text{ kW}$$

$$Q=\sqrt{100^2 - 80^2} = 60\text{ KVAR}$$

$$S=\frac{80}{0.8} = 100\text{ kVA}$$

***Added together***

$$P= 80\text{ kW} + 300\text{ kW} = 380\text{ kW}$$

$$Q= 400\text{ KVAR} - 60\text{ KVAR} = 340\text{ KVAR}$$

$$S= \sqrt{380^2+340^2} = 509.9\text{ kVA}$$

Overall power factor = \$\frac{P}{S} = \frac{380}{509.9} = 0.75\$ lagging.

So reactive power = 340 kVAR and pf = 0.75 lagging.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. It's an unwritten rule here that if you want homework help you must at least attempt to solve the problem. Please try to figure it out and update the question with your work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework problem with no effort to solve demonstrated.

Comment: All you need to know is the definition of kW, kVA, kVAR and power factor. Then the calculation only requires a pencil and paper or 4 function calculator.

Comment: A good place to start would be a couple of right-angle triangles. On one you have the hypotenuse on the other you have 'x' and on both, you have the angle. Remember the definitions as Charles Cowie mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Charles your comment put me on the right track, wasn't as hard as I first thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes.

---

For any future readers, the key formulae here are:

$$ P_{kW} = S_{kVA} * pf $$
$$ S_{kVA}^2 = P_{kW}^2 + Q_{kvar}^2 \quad\text{therefore}\quad Q_{kvar} = \sqrt{S_{kVA}^2 - P_{kW}^2}$$

Which can be derived from an example of the power triangle below and the fact that \$ pf = \cos\theta \$.
[image: Power Triangle showing leading and lagging loads]